# Why item inserted in object?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

I found an groupby implementation in ES6 for grouping this data object:

```
const pets = [
    {type:"Dog", name:"Spot"},
    {type:"Cat", name:"Tiger"},
    {type:"Dog", name:"Rover"}, 
    {type:"Cat", name:"Leo"}
];
```

But, why "item" also inserted in object, as we already inserted a keys [item[key]], and values ...(result[item[key]] || []).

Also how to console.log() "item" in such notation to know, what data is there (inside object like)

```
{...result,
[item[key]]: [
      ...(result[item[key]] || []),
      console.log(item),] // ?
}
```

```
const groupBy = (items, key) => items.reduce(
  (result, item) => ({
    ...result,
    [item[key]]: [
      ...(result[item[key]] || []),
      item,    // ?
    ],
  }), 
  {},
);
```

Comment: *"But, why "item" also inserted in object..."* I don't really understand, but I'm trying to.  I don't see "item" as text anywhere before that explanation sentence.  What "item" are you referring to?

Comment: @Yousaf since you're pushing a new value and the code is mostly imperative, I don't see a point in using `reduce`. `for..of` would be a better choice.

Comment: @marzelin there are multiple ways to achieve the desired result. Since OP's question is related to `reduce()`, i didn't want to present an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result[item[key]]` stores the previously added items. `item` is there to add the current item to the array.

To log `item`, you can use the fact that `console.log` returns a falsy value and use `||` (OR) operator:

```
(console.log(item) || item)
```

```js
const pets = [
    {type:"Dog", name:"Spot"},
    {type:"Cat", name:"Tiger"},
    {type:"Dog", name:"Rover"}, 
    {type:"Cat", name:"Leo"}
];

const groupBy = (items, key) => items.reduce(
  (result, item) => ({
    ...result,
    [item[key]]: [
      ...(result[item[key]] || []),
      (console.log(item) || item),    // !!
    ],
  }), 
  {},
);

groupBy(pets, "type")
```

Imperative (perhaps easier to understand for beginners) version of `groupBy`:

```js
const groupBy = (items, key) => {
  const result = {};
  for (const item of items) {
    const arr = result[item[key]];
    if (arr) {
      arr.push(item);
    } else {
      result[item[key]] = [item];
    }
  };
  return result;
};
```